# Auto Layout inverts views horizontally iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout

I  haven’t been able to pinpoint the cause of an issue i’m having , regarding our company project.

I have notice that in all the auto layout views in the project , the views that appear to be attached to a specific side in interface builder, 
are presented on the opposite side after the build.

I.e when i am adding a view to a  storyboard view controller, than creating an horizontal space constraint to it’s superview leading margin (left side) it appears ok on interface builder and the preview, but after the build, it appears to be inverted on simulator/device , the view has the same horizontal space but to the opposite side ( right side on this example).

The same issue happens to all the views that are already were on the app (the views that supposed to be on the right side appear to be on the left side and vice versa )

I spend hours to figure out what cause this invert with out any success (the issue happens only in our project), i even tried to change the project definitions according to a new one.

I’ll appreciate if you will be able to help me on this matter.

I'am adding the screenshot of the view in interface builder, the preview and the simulator[image]

Comment: Could you at least demonstrate that behavior on some demo project?

Comment: Take your project, start removing things until you have an example view that's broken, and make that public. If you can rip out the simplest exemplary view, that would be great.

Comment: This already been done, i created a blank view controller and forced the app to start with it. The same thing happened when i added a view to the view controller on storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kinds of horizontal constraint — universal and language-bound.

- The **universal** constraints are called Left and Right. The meanings of these constraints never change.
- The **language-bound** constraints are called Leading and Trailing. Their meaning depends on the language environment in which the app is running. If the language is like English, Leading is left and Trailing is right; but if the language is like Arabic or Hebrew, which are written from right to left, Leading is right and Trailing is left. This allows labels to be constructed that work correctly regardless of writing direction.

This distinction is drawn in Interface Builder with the "Respect language direction" menu item; to get the universal Left-Right constraints, *uncheck* it:

[image]

So, you may be using Leading and Trailing correctly and appropriately for some views, but it sounds from your complaint as if you have accidentally used Leading and Trailing for some views where you meant to use Left and Right.

Comment: The language on the device is english. So according to this useful info it is not supposed to happened. Btw how do i change/create a universal left/right constraint instead of a leading /trailing?

Comment: "Btw how do i change/create a universal left/right constraint" Added that info to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot , problem solved. The thing that i don't understand is why did it happen if my device/simulator language running on an english system language?

Comment: It's all about your localizations. Look at your storyboard's Base language.

Comment: Did  you meant  the value for  "Localization native development region" key on the plist?

Comment: I meant exactly what I said.

Comment: Thanks, i checked it and it was value "he" for key "Localization native development region" in the plist, i guess that could also be the cause to the storyboard behaviour

Comment: Is there anyway to uncheck the "respect language direction" by default?

Comment: Correct. You are designing in Hebrew but running in English. No, no such way AFAIK.

Comment: But it's about localizations, as I said. You have both RTL and LTR localizations of your storyboard; you have not revealed what they all are, but I can guess Hebrew and English at a minimum. If you didn't have those localizations, you wouldn't have this issue. You should not have localized the storyboard if you were not prepared for this.

Answer (score 1):

It happened when you have Right-to-left system language, for example hebrew or arabic. It's default Apple feature.

If you change system language to English everything should be ok.

Comment: If you meant to the device language, it is not relevant, my device/simulator are defined with english system language. Changing it to right to left language didn't helped ether.

Comment: Try to change language and locale.